# Question posted by someone 2-3 hours ago on Hamiltonian Monte Carlo

Tags: support

About two or three hours ago I read a question on "why Hamiltonian Monte Carlo works, in plain english" or something like that. I had an idea for an answer and a couple references, but I can't find it anymore. It must have been closed or deleted. Is there any way to find out? I understand that if the question had been closed a day or a week ago, it would probably be impossible, but since the event is relatively recent, maybe it's not the case.

Comment: You can put `deleted:yes` into the search box  - but I couldn't find this one.

Comment: hmmm, then I guess the question was closed, not deleted. No way to find out if that's the case, right? I would like to know who was the OP - maybe she/he will post a similar question later, which I could (try to) answer.

Comment: Closed questions appear in search results by default. I tried searching for questions with the `mcmc` tag & found [Why Hamitonial dynamics is better than random walk proposal in MCMC?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/261571/17230).

Comment: Thanks! So, it hasn't been either closed or deleted. It's just that the title has a typo, thus I couldn't find it by searching for `Hamiltonian`. Looks like the first thing I have to do is to edit that title :)

Comment: @Scortchi When I try searching with `deleted:yes` in the search box, I get `Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content` message. And I have all possible non-mod privileges unlocked. Can it be that it works differently for the mods?

Comment: Please note that this is a perfect occasion to post and answer the question yourself (if it's not a dupe). I'd certainly be interested in reading your answer!

Comment: @Sycorax thanks, I really appreciate that a user with your experience is interested in an answer of mine :) the answer to the original question (or, better, to my interpretation of the question,  which corresponds to that of other users) is [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/261677/58675). It's mostly based on a nice paper by Michael Betancourt. I added an explicit computation of the typical set in a classic case, and a few words about my experience with HMC. I'm thinking to add something on the computational overload of the method.

Comment: @amoeba: Must be different - I don't get that message